# database access plugin for eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

May I know is there any plug-in for eclipse with which I can access my database through eclipse? I am using both db2 and oracle so it should be db independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DBViewer](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/zigen/home/plugin/dbviewer/about_en.html)** looks good (disclaimer: not tested directly)

[image: DBViewer]

---

An older one would be **[QuantumDB](http://quantum.sourceforge.net/)**

[image: DBViewer perspective]

Answer (score 1):

One such plugin is [QuantumDB](http://quantum.sourceforge.net/).